# (Top Nav) Search icon blinks when pressing ENTER but not with the mouse

Tags: bug, search-box

I noticed the search icon at the top navigation section blinks a few times  (and fades out) when pressing ENTER [while searching for something on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is+forgetting+to+echo+off-topic%3F), but not if I use the mouse. (See the animated .gif below.)

It reacted the same way in Stack Overflow also.

Is this a (global) bug or normal behaviour?

*For the record:*

My search for *"Search icon blinks when pressing ENTER but not with the mouse"* on meta didn't yield results. I used the following search criteria which rendered no results about it: [Search icon blinks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Search+icon+blinks).

Side note: I'm not sure if this question needed another tag related to this.

---

**Troubleshooting tests I performed:**

This seems to only be the case with Firefox (53.0.2 is my version on Windows 7), but doesn't do it on a Linux box with the same version of Firefox.

Nor does it do this with Opera for Windows.

---

As stated in comments:

> I feel like you should be asking your browsers developers whether this is by design. Of course this is not "by design" from Stack Overflow's point of view, but what can Stack Overflow possibly do to change this, short of submitting a patch to your browser's maintainer? – meagar♦

I tend to think that this could be the case, but why am I getting different results from my tests above?

---

**Edit:**

I managed to get an animated screen capture of what I see:

[image: blinking example]

**N.B.:** Again, this **doesn't do the same thing on my Linux (mint) box with the same version of Firefox**. So as meagar stated, I can't understand why this would be a browser-specific issue unless the different OS's use a different UI / JS internal method, so I don't know what to look for specifically.

Comment: Pressing "enter" submits the search form and does a full page reload, parts of the UI will flicker. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @meagar So, clicking the mouse doesn't do a full page reload?

Comment: @meagar I edited my question in regards to this, adding *" or normal behaviour"*. What my above comment should have been was missing the "why" and been *"why doesn't it flicker with the mouse; do both methods use different searching actions?"*. I just found it strange that the icon blinked like that. So this brings me to, if this was to be tagged as status design?

Comment: I feel like you should be asking your browsers developers whether this is by design. Of course this is not "by design" from Stack Overflow's point of view, but what can Stack Overflow possibly do to change this, short of submitting a patch to your browser's maintainer?

Comment: @meagar You could be right. Could you take a look at an edit I made to the question?

Comment: Oh yeah, I've been meaning to ask about this annoying blinking thing.

Comment: I'm wondering why my question received a downvote. It's no big deal but I'm just curious is all.

Comment: @AndrasDeak So I'm not alone on this then. Moderators seem to think that my question could be off-topic.

Comment: I think meagar's comments come from a JS expert rather than a site moderator.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'd say you may very well be right. If he's a JS guru, then he could have probably have told me that different OS' react/treat JS differently in the same version of Firefox; there's sort of a hidden message in there ;-) not aimed at you here. I pinged him a couple of days ago about my edit but I've yet to get a response from him, along with the other additional edit I made to the question.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to reproduce this bug using Firefox 52.0.2 64-bit on Linux. Only the search box flickers, not the entire page. Flickering stops once the new page is loaded.

This may be a visual glitch/bug in Firefox, but I am not confident enough to say that it is. I also don't know if other browsers suffer from the same issue. I cannot reproduce the issue in Chrome.

**Steps to reproduce.** There are two ways to trigger this behavior.

1. Focus the search field.
2. Either

   1. submit the search using the enter key, or
   2. reload the page using F5 or some other shortcut.

**Cause.** This is partial speculation, but this is what I believe happens. The search box transitions to a state where it is wider, has the search button visible and has a blue outline when it is focused. The current page is in this state, while the page to be loaded is in the state where the field is not focused. Firefox somehow blinks between the two states while loading the new page.

Because clicking the search icon will blur the input, using the mouse will not trigger the same behavior. This leads to the following idea.

**Workaround.** Blurring the search input when the search form is submitted seems to avert the flickering behavior. I tested this by entering the following in my [browser console](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/2288/console#t=201705201435217417093&a=remarks-opening-the-console-0).

```js
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.target.querySelector('.js-search-field').blur(); });
```

This could be implemented by the Stack Exchange team to make the behavior consistent across browsers. It can obviously also be added to user scripts, for those of us who don't like the flickering.

Comment: *"Only the search box flickers, not the entire page."* - I added an animated screencap to the question. It's not the search "box" that flickers, but the search glass "icon" that flashes (and fades out); that was added in an edit also. However, and also added, was emphasis on it "not" flickering on Linux (mint), only in Windows (7). As for the workaround; thanks for that but I was really looking to get an explanation but didn't really get anything concreted. Meagar's comment wasn't much help and I seem to not be getting the attention I was expecting for this. I'll +1 though, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I saw the screencap and indeed, that is what I see. That is in fact what I meant when I wrote that the search box flickers, I suppose my wording could be improved... I completely believe you when you write that you cannot reproduce it on Linux. I merely state that I can. I'm using Debian, for what it's worth. I wish I could provide an explanation, but I cannot. I merely wanted to provide this workaround, as it does solve the problem, whatever its explanation :-) Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Well, you've provided a lot more than what I'd of expected from the people who know how everything works; after all, "they" built it and maintain it for different browsers and OS'. I'm disappointed and a bit annoyed, TBH as to what I was told about this; having to contact the developers at Mozilla; I didn't get that and to submit a patch. Honestly, Firefox 53.x.x  is one animal; Windows and Linux are two "different" animals. One of those isn't treating the "other animal" correctly somewhere/somehow ;-) Edit: I feel like I'm being swept under the rug, as it were.